# jquery selected option in clone

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/tejaskot/3enz8fmy/1/

how do i selected option in jquery clone for next row
jsfiddle has my code please give advice for that
i have tried many way but not got success and i am new in jquery that why i don't know to slow this problem please give fast answer on that if any query please comment here thank you in advance.

**html code**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed table-hover" id="dynamic_field">  
               <th>Course Name</th>


               <tr id="id" class="trrow"> 
                    <td class="col-md-4">
                        <select class="form-control select2 selectCourse" data-id="1"  id="course_id_1" name="course_id[]" data-live-search="true">
                    <option value="" selected> Select Course Name</option>
         <option value="1">m. s. office</option>
         <option value="2">windows 7</option>
         <option value="3">Test</option>
                        <option value="14">test1</option>


                         </select >
                     </td>



                    <td class="col-md-2"><input type="button" name="add" value="Add Row" class="btn btn-success"></td>

               </tr>  
        </table>
```

**jquery code**

```
$("input.btn-success").on('click', function() 
            {
                $latest_tr  = $('#dynamic_field tr:last');


var selects = $latest_tr.find("select");

                //Destroy select2
                //$('select.select2').select2('destroy');

                //Cloning tr
                $clone = $latest_tr.clone();


                $latest_tr.after($clone);




     $(selects).each(function(i) 
                    {
                        var select = this;
 $clone.find('select.select2').eq(i).val($(select).val());                                                               
                        });

                //creating select2
                $('select.select2').select2();



                //$clone.find(':text').val('');
                //$clone.find(':textarea').val('');

                $clone.find('.btn-success').val('X');
                $clone.find('.btn-success').addClass('btn-danger').removeClass('btn-success');

                    $('#dynamic_field tr').each(function (i) 
                    {
                        i++;
                        $(this).find('tr:last');
                        if (i === 0)
                            return;
                        i--;
                        var selectinput = $(this).find('select');
                        var textinput = $(this).find('input');
                        var textarea = $(this).find('textarea');

                        selectinput.eq(0).attr('data-id', '' + i);
                        selectinput.eq(0).attr('id', 'course_id_' + i);
                        selectinput.eq(1).attr('id', 'parent_id_' + i);
                        textinput.eq(0).attr('id', 'topic_name' + i);
                        textarea.eq(0).attr('id', 'topic_description' + i);
                    });


                    /*Removing Row */
                    $(document).on('click', '.btn-danger', function()
                    {  
                            $(this).closest(".trrow").remove();
                    }); 
            });
```

Comment: you need to clone only select box with select2.js property..?

Comment: i have solw it  thank you @manu

Comment: ok welcome @lana

Comment: Please either answer your own question or delete it.